# Return all values from a column to a single cell if they are in the same product family in that row and if the price is higher in that row

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet, vlookup, concatenation

I'm struggling to find a formula or VBA that will perform this function.

I have the following columns: 'price', 'image code', 'product family' and 'alternative products' columns.

I want to populate the '**alternative products**' column with all **image codes** that are in the same **product family** of the item in that row (not including its own code) and that have a higher **price** than the item in that row. So a few image codes will be returned to one cell with && between each code for website and sage upload.

I am looking for a formula or code that can be applied to 4000 products. I have looked at combining vlookup and concat but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated as am still learning the art of excel.

Comment: look into the tag [TextJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textjoin).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AltProducts()

Dim ImageCodeArray(4000,1) as Variant  'array to hold all image codes
Dim AlreadyUsed(4000,1) as Variant     'array to keep track of already used image codes
Dim R as Range                         'first cell containing data in product family column
Dim R1 as Range                        'first cell containing data in image code column
Dim R2 as Range                        'first cell containing data (a blank) in alternative products column


Set R = ActiveSheet.Range("first cell in Product Family column, under header")
Set R1 = ActiveSheet.Range("first cell in Image Code column, under header")
Set R2 = ActiveSheet.Range("first cell in Alternative Products column, under header")

'this piece builds a 2d array with product family and image code for lookup

For i = 0 to 4000                      
    ImageCodeArray(i,0) = R.Offset(x,0)
    ImageCodeArray(i,1) = R1.Offset(x,0)
Next i

For x = 0 to 4000
    For z = 0 to 4000

'begins looping through product family, and looks up the first entry in the array that matches the product family we're looking for

        If ImageCodeArray(z,0) = R.Offset(x,0) Then    
            For y = 0 to 4000

'Checks to see if we have already included the image code associated with the product family we just found in the alternative items cell. If we have, skip to the next iteration.

                If AlreadyUsed(y) = ImageCodeArray(z,1) Then Goto Skip  
            Next y

'if the image code has not already been used, this next step adds it into the appropriate cell in the alternative products column

            R2.Offset(x,0) = R2.Offset(x,0) & ImageCodeArray(z,1) & "&&"

'add the image code we just added onto the already used list

            AlreadyUsed(z) = ImageCodeArray(z,1)     
        End If
    Skip:
    Next z
Erase AlreadyUsed(4000,1)

'Move down one cell in the product family column, repeat process

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response I will try this out :D

Comment: Hi Theodore - thank you for your help. I am getting a compile error when i run this code (Wrong number of dimensions) for the 'If AlreadyUsed (y)' part.

Comment: Also to make things more of a mission I have been asked to include three image codes for each product - two having a higher price and one a lower price. So each product has three alternative products. I am looking in to your code now and seeing how i can adapt it - however im such a vba beginner so this is not easy (but nothing worth knowing is, right?)